# Sorting array values so they correspond to other array being sorted (when it's actually unchanged)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am totally new to Java and this question might be simple but I really need help as I struggled to find any possible solution to this problem I have.

At first, a short example to describe my problem. Let's say I have two array lists:

```
// prices
[14, 2, 1, 10]

// ID numbers which correspond to these prices
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

My goal is to sort these IDs so they would correspond to random integers being sorted in ascending order. In other words, the result should be:

```
// IDs sorted so they correspond to prices being in ascending order
[2, 1, 3, 0]
```

And random integers array should remain the same.

Is it possible? Could you help me with ideas how to do it?

Comment: Don't use two parallel arrays. Instead, use a single array (or list) of objects, where each object has an ID and a price.

Comment: Is the second array "ID numbers", or are they *index* values? E.g. could the second array be `[3,4,7,9]`? Or are they always consecutive starting at `0`, i.e. indexes into the first array?

Comment: Similar to Andreas comment, a `TreeMap` could be used, with `ID` as a key, and `price` as a value.

Comment: @Andreas It looks to me like they are always zero-based indexes.

Comment: k4rina it looks to me like JB has the right answer.  You'll need to make a class to store the pairs, then make a compare method or a comparator for that class, to compare on the price value.  Then iterate through your arrays, building an object for each pair of entries and inserting them into some self-sorting structure such as a TreeSet.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Just because the one-and-only example provided happens to (also) be 0-based indexes, doesn't mean that's always the case, which is why I'm asking OP for *clarification*, not other peoples *guesses*. I can guess myself, and we can all guess wrong, which is why I'm not providing alternate solution without first getting *definitive* clarification.

Comment: Sure.  I just found the question clear.  Sorry for trying to help.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica The thing is, if our guess is right, and they *are* index values, then there is a solution that is "easier" than JB's, i.e. doesn't require restructuring the data. Not that JB's comment wouldn't be better anyway, since parallel arrays are bad. Java is an OO language, and you should use it right.

Comment: @Andreas If you post it, I will upvote it (assuming I believe it's correct).  It's always possible that someone other than k4rina will find it useful.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica Done

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "ID numbers" are actually indexes into the first array, like shown in the example, then you can sort like this:

```
int[] prices = { 14, 2, 1, 10 };
int[] idNumbers = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };

int[] sorted = Arrays.stream(idNumbers).boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(i -> prices[i]))
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
```

*Output*

```
[2, 1, 3, 0]
```

Unfortunately, Java's Runtime Library doesn't provide a `sort` method for sorting arrays of primitives using a `Comparator` (or primitive equivalent), so boxing and unboxing the values while streaming is the easiest solution.